# How to press and release using asyncio in python?

Tags: python, python-asyncio, keyboard-events

I want to make keyboard manager with python for the reinforcement learning environemnt. I have some problem with time.sleep() synchronized with environment

This is What I want :

```
import asyncio
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller

class KeyboardManager:
    def __init__(self):
        self.keyboard = Controller()

    def release(self):
        self.keyboard.release(Key.left)
        self.keyboard.release(Key.right)

    async def press_right(self, press_time): 
        self.keyboard.press(Key.right)
        await asyncio.sleep(press_time)
        self.keyboard.release(Key.right)
```

And Use this class with another script

```
class Env:
    def action_right(self):
        self.keyboard_manager.press_right(10)
```

this code is not work.
I guess I have to listen asyncio loop somewhere.
Is there any good Idea?
please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have tagged the `press_right` function with `async`, you convert its return value to a coroutine that has to be awaited somewhere.
You could just propagate the *asynchronousity* to `Env.action_right` by:

```py
class Env:
    async def action_right(self):
        await self.keyboard_manager.press_right(10)
```

But at some point wou'll have to wait your async code. For instance you could handle the asyncio event loop yourself with `loop.run_until_complete()`:

```py
from asyncio import get_event_loop

class Env:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        self.loop = get_event_loop()

    def action_right(self):
        loop.run_until_complete(self.keyboard_manager.press_right(10))
```

If you are using Python 3.7, you could just:

```py
import asyncio

class Env:
    def action_right(self):
        asyncio.run(self.keyboard_manager.press_right(10))
```

Anyway, I guess you don't want to wait your async code at that point, because I can't see the point in making `KeywordManager.press_right` async in that case.

If your framework is meant to be used with async code, the event loop may be handled by the framework and you just need to propagate your async code (as is the case of aiohttp server for instance). Instead, if you are using the RL library `gym` you are not given such feature and I don't think using some async code will be of much help.

Comment: Thanks, it works. but when I do some loop, I got a the error " TypeError: An asyncio.Future, a coroutine or an awaitable is required ". 
I think I call the function too much... that before call the press function, I have to cancel the all coroutine task.. Is it right?
thanks again.

Comment: It's hard to debug that from a comment. I would encourage you to write a new question with the loop and a full explanation